# How to import a spreadsheet into Numbers from an email attachment? 

Tags: ipad, numbers

I want to know how to open a spreadheet email attachement in the Numbers app on the iPad.

Here are the steps I have taken with no luck:

1. On the iPad I open my email.
2. I see a spreadsheet attachment.
3. I click it and it previews.

Now how do I get the spreadhseet into Numbers?

The [Apple directions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4067) say the following:

**'OpenReceive as an email attachment. Preview the spreadsheet and tap the `“Open in”` button to open Numbers.'**

***My problem*** is I cant find the `"Open in"` option on the iPad??

Comment: You might just have to tap the screen once to bring up the title bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This screen shot is from Keynote for iPad, but Numbers for iPad is pretty much the same:

[image: Keynote iPad preview sshot]

When you view the file in Preview mode, the title bar of the document should look pretty similar to the above. Over there on the right is the <kbd>**Open in…**</kbd> button.

There *might* be a [image] button that you have to click first before you see the <kbd>**Open in…**</kbd> button.

Other ways to transfer files to your iPad:

- [Use iTunes file sharing to import iWork documents](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4088)
- [Use the iWork.com public beta](https://help.apple.com/iwork/1.3/safari/index.html#tan7271a09d)
- [Use MobileMe iDisk or a WebDAV server](https://help.apple.com/iwork/1.3/safari/index.html#tana34d948e)

Comment: Dropbox is also an excellent and free route: the Dropbox app shows a preview (if possible) and allows you to open the file with any app on the iPad that can handle it, using a menu very similar to the one in your screenshot. http://dropbox.com/

Comment: @Matthew - I just listed the transfer methods that Apple recommends and documents. Even [a Dropbox fangirl like me](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/423/what-are-good-web-based-workflow-solutions-for-graphic-designers/464#464) thought that, given four different ways to do one task, a fifth would be overkill ;-) .

Comment: I hear ya. I just wanted to add the suggestion because iDisk costs money and setting up your own WebDAV server is a huge pain in the butt. :)

Answer (score 1):

ok the anwer is not to open the attachment. Touch and hold the closed attachment and then it will ask you if you want to open in numbers. Once you have done that it will save automatically.

Answer (score 0):

New Answer: 
1) Open the attachment: 
2) Select the icon as if you were going to forward in mail: 
3) I then received the option to mail, save in numbers etc.

I just saved an excel file to numbers on my IPhone 6. 
No I am not a techno geek but a 65 year old ex CPM type

Philip B.